# API-PLATFORM - model with object serialized to string at endpoint

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I faced the problem with generating React components with **api-platform-generate-crud**.
Model has property that is object email.
I have serializer that make my email object a string.
API endpoint is serving string.

It works for GET & POST.
When I try to generate React components error message is

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Looking deeper into it, looks like that generator still see my ***email*** as object not a string.

Any idea how I can force API to 'see' email property as string not object ?

Comment: Can you post your entity definition and the custom normalizer you use if any?

Comment: 1. [Partial entity](https://gist.github.com/mysiar/c664d089e51a6107612d7e22d79f650b)  
2. [Normalizer](https://gist.github.com/mysiar/2f44a8980133d3df9d82ce6413e3adc6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data model you define is authoritative. Types in the Hydra documentation reflect the ones in PHP classes.
Here, the `email` property is of type `object`. If you set the related data as a `string` somewhere, you don't respect this contract anymore. The Hydra documentation is not in sync with the returned data.

You can change the type of the `email` property in the Hydra documentation by [decorating](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_decoration.html) the `api_platform.hydra.normalizer.documentation` service.

But I would recommend to keep the PHP classes' structure of your entities as close as possible of the structure exposed through the API.
Your classes should reflect the output of the API. You can use custom data providers to deal with more complex data structure (ex: ORM entities) before hydrating the structure to expose.